# Is EMF/EMR additive (two devices produce twice the EMR)?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, measurements

I'm interested in electromagnetic radiation radiated from home appliances.

Wanted to know if I have two phones (for arguments sake assume that they are perfectly identical) and they both are in sync (connecting to the base station at the same time) - will that result in a roughly x2 increase in EMR compared to just one phone? Or will it be much more complicated than that due to interference between the devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have the same wave, but the final result depends on orientation. It is like when you add two vector fields together, you'll have double the vector field but only if it is the same in direction and magnitude. If they are the same field, but displaced or rotated, the magnitude of homologous vectors will coincide, but the direction will be different, and which vectors are added to which others will also vary.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Any studies that you know that tested this empirically with a statistical approach (like dumping many mobile phones into one room and checking the correlation between the phone count and the EMR increase)?

Comment: The mathematical model of waves predicts the behaviour. I don't know who tested this, but it was probably done by someone early in the 20th century.